# Ruby -- How to add values to an array in a loop?

Tags: arrays, ruby, loops

I'm trying to write a program that asks users to enter words, and then I want the words entered to be stored in an array which is later to be printed on the screen after they press the return key.

Here is my code, but it doesn't work:

```
while loop do
  puts 'Enter your words:'

  user_input = gets.chomp.capitalize

  if user_input != ''
    user_words = Array.new
    user_input.push user_words
  elsif user_input == ''
    puts user_words.to_s
    break
  end
end
```

Could someone help me?

Comment: What *specific problem* are you having right now? We can't help you very well if you don't have a problem. What is your code doing right now that you don't want it to, or what is your code not doing that you'd like it to be doing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many problems with your code, here they are:

1. Having `while` and `loop` in one statement is useless
2. `puts 'Enter your words:'` should be declared outside of the loop
3. `user_words` should be declared outside of the loop to accumulate the values
4. `puts user_words.to_s` should be outside of the loop to print all values in the very end
5. `push` should be called on an array not on a string
6. `elsif user_input == ""` is excessive, could be replaced with `else`
7. `Array.new` is worse than `[]`

Here is my solution:

```
puts 'Enter your words:'

words = []

loop do
  input = gets.chomp.capitalize
  break if input == ''
  words << input
end

puts words.to_s
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I was able to edit the code you provided to make it do exactly what I wanted and then some (https://pastebin.com/embed_js/y1ayGUDi)

Comment: If you don't mind, would you point out my errors for me? I'm new to programming and would greatly appreciate it the help!

Comment: So basically, I've spent hours working on this problem. I'll admit that I'm a newborn baby trying to speak a new language here, and this was a challenge in learntoprogram by Chris Pine (free version online). My thought process was the following (this may take several post.) 1. Get user to input words. 2. Take that information and then store it into an array. 3. print out the stored information after pressing enter. I tried to write my code following that logic, but failed to do so. It makes more sense after you posted your answer, but I don't know why you used the true statement.

Comment: Also, is loop do and while the same exact thing?